# Developing PowerPoint AddIn, getting Office 365 error

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, office-addins, office-web-app

After creating Office Add-In template project, on execution I am getting an error which says application isn't installed in this computer.

What should I have to install? I ave already installed Office Tools from Visual Studio installation.

I have Visual Studio 2017 Project Type was : Office Add-In ( PowerPoint Web Add In) Office version is : 2007

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a silly question ... I work in VBA, not Visual Studio ... but do you have PowerPoint installed? Or possibly the version of PPT that your project is targeting?

Comment: Powerpoint Office version 2007 . I think i need to install Office version 2013.

Answer (score 0):

A Web Add-in (which uses the Office JS APIs) only works with Office 365. You'd need to create a VSTO project for an Add-in that runs in any earlier version of Office.

Comment: OK. I am really sorry I am very beginner at creating VSTO project. I don't know what option to choose. Of course web solution wont be my selection.

Comment: For example, I am starting from the task ...

Creation of VSTO add-in for PowerPoint (C#) that will draw a red rectangle around the currently selected shape.